# How to Intersect on first element of tuple in two different lists of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, intersection

I have two lists of tuples:

```py
a = [(4,5),(7,6),(3,2),(9,6),(25,7)]
b = [(4,6),(7,2),(6,1),(57,12)]
```

I want a list containing the tuples where the values of the first elements intersect.

```py
c = [(4,5),(4,6),(7,6),(7,2)]
```

I tried the following code

```py
c=[]
for i in a:
m,n=i
    for j,k in b:
        if m==j:
            i=i[:]
            i=i+(j,k)
            c=i
print c
```

output: `(7,6,7,2)`

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happen if `a=[(4,5),(7,6)]` and `b=[(7,2),(4,6)]`? Will `c=[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, you did not update the value of c, because you equating it with i every time. Thus, the c will be replaced for every if condition is met.

secondly, i=i+(j,k) will combine two list together. for example, in your case when you equate i = (7,6) and j = 7 and k = 2, (by observation, the if-condition is met) then the i = (7,6,7,2).

I believe this will solve your problem.

```
a=[(4,5),(7,6),(3,2),(9,6),(25,7)]
b=[(4,6),(7,2),(6,1),(57,12)]
c=[]
for i in a:
m,n=i
for j,k in b:
    if m==j:
        c.append(i)
        break

for i in b:
m,n=i
for j,k in a:
    if m==j:
        c.append(i)
        break

print (c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a bad question since your question is not very clear, I will try to give my understanding of what you actually want.

So you want to iterate through both list, and if there is an element in `a` with the same first tuple-element in `b` at the same position, then put both of them in the list `c`.

Then this is what you want:

```
for el_a, el_b in zip(a,b):
    if el_a[0]==el_b[0]:
        c.append(el_a)
        c.append(el_b)
```

The problem with your code is that `i=i+(j,k)` will combine the tuple into longer tuple, in your case, it's combining `(7,6)` with `(7,2)`, which becomes `(7,6,7,2)`. You don't need this step.

The second problem is that, to add element into a list, you need to do `c.append(element)`, not `c=i` like you're doing right now.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. In you solution the zip function truncates the list length to the length of the shortest argument sequence. Hence it would not remain valid.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this with the module itertools

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain(*[e for e in zip(a,b) if e[0][0] == e[1][0]]))
```